# PHP: Does strip_tags() strip self closing XHTML tags or not?

Tags: php, strip-tags

PHP manual says

> 5.3.4     strip_tags() no longer strips self-closing XHTML tags unless the self-closing XHTML tag is also given in allowable_tags.

But when I do this (5.5):

```
$text = "<base/><br/>World<hr><input/>";

echo strip_tags($text);
```

The output is `World` i.e it does strip self closing XHTML tags.

Comment: You're echoing it out... to the cli or the browser? Try `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: try `var_dump($text);`

Comment: `string 'World' (length=5)`

Comment: I am looking into it, but at first sight it looks like the wording of the manual is wrong. As "strip_tags() no longer strips self-closing XHTML tags unless the self-closing XHTML tag is also given in allowable_tags." makes no sense

Comment: @PeeHaa, don't overlook this note - In PHP 5.3.4 and later, you will also need to include the self-closing XHTML tag to strip these from str. - I know it is counterintuitive, but that's how the decided.

Comment: @PeeHaa Is correct here. It doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: If you want to strip XHTML tags you will need to include them in allowable_tags. That's how they designed it.

Comment: The same thing is said in two places, not one. I think this is how it was, but later did they change the function and forgot to update description?

Answer (score 5):

The docs in this case are simply wrong.

`strip_tags()` without any allowed tags strips self closing tags just fine. What is changed however is that as of >= 5.3.4 self closing tags are ignored:

```
$string = "foo<br>bar<br/>baz<br />\r\n";

echo strip_tags($string); // foobarbaz
echo strip_tags($string, '<br>'); // foo<br>bar<br/>baz<br />
echo strip_tags($string, '<br/>'); // foobarbaz
echo strip_tags($string, '<br />'); // foobarbaz
echo strip_tags($string, '<br><br/>'); // foo<br>bar<br/>baz<br/>
```

<strike>I've [created a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70402) for it to fix it in the docs.</strike>

The [docs are updated](http://news.php.net/php.doc.cvs/13684) to reflect the actual correct behavior.

<strike>However the fact that self closing and "normal" tags need to be defined separately seem odd to me at first, so *maybe* that needs to be fixed as well.</strike>

When reading the original [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53319) it is not entirely clear to me what has been fixed and what the expected output would be from that so I need to investigate a bit more.

<sub><sub>My initial assumption that both self-closing as well as non-self-closing tags should be added was wrong.</sub></sub>

Comment: I think you got it wrong. What the manual is trying to say (but fails) is you *don't* need to allow self-closing and "normal" tags separately in order to preserve both, as you would in PHP < 5.3.4. In other words: `strip_tags` no longer strips `<br/>` if you only put `<br>` in allowed tags. Compare: https://3v4l.org/GntM3